# Stereographic projection of graph from sphere to plane - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, tikz-3dplot

I want to create a tikz-picture to map a planar graph from the sphere to the plane. While this has already been done for similar purposes I didn't find any picture that included the edges of the graph.

I already use some template from [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/tikz/stereographic-projection/stereographic-projection.tex) (the code is there and well commented, thus including a MWE). But im way to unfamiliar with tikz for adding what I want.

I 'only' need minor changes to the MWE, to be exact I added this little self-painted modification for you to see the difference. The exacte location of points and edges doesn't matter so much, but edges on the sphere should be round. In fact it would already help me to get some lines in the graphic.

```
% Source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
%% helper macros
\begin{tikzpicture} % CENT
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}
%% some definitions

\def\R{2.5} % sphere radius
\def\angEl{35} % elevation angle
\def\angAz{-105} % azimuth angle
\def\angPhi{-40} % longitude of point P
\def\angBeta{19} % latitude of point P

%% working planes

\pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
\tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={cos(\angAz),sin(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),-sin(\angAz),
                              cos(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),(0,-\H)}}}
\LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
\LongitudePlane[pzplane]{\angEl}{\angPhi}
\LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

%% draw xyplane and sphere

\draw[xyplane] (-2*\R,-2*\R) rectangle (2.2*\R,2.8*\R);
\fill[ball color=white] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
\draw (0,0) circle (\R);

%% characteristic points

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
\path[pzplane] (\angBeta:\R) coordinate[mark coordinate] (P);
\path[pzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (PE);
\path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);
\path (PE) ++(0,-\H) coordinate (Paux); % to aid Phat calculation
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (Phat) at (intersection cs: first line={(N)--(P)},
                                        second line={(S)--(Paux)});

%% draw meridians and latitude circles

\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0} % equator
\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz} % xzplane
\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz+90} % yzplane
\DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angPhi} % pzplane

%% draw xyz coordinate system

\draw[xyplane,<->] (1.8*\R,0) node[below] {$x,\xi$} -- (0,0) -- (0,2.4*\R)
    node[right] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,-\H) -- (0,1.6*\R) node[above] {$z$};

%% draw lines and put labels

\draw[blue,dashed] (P) -- (N) +(0.3ex,0.6ex) node[above left,black] {$\mathbf{N}$};
\draw[blue] (P) -- (Phat) node[above right,black] {$\mathbf{\hat{P}}$};
\path (S) +(0.4ex,-0.4ex) node[below] {$\mathbf{0}$};
\draw (P) node[above right] {$\mathbf{P}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Goal.]

While I am aware that I'm not the first to ask this general question my question should be unique. I'd appreciate any tips!

Comment: This [link](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/) it's modication of your code that make something similar of what you want.